# DynamoDB "The provided key element does not match the schema error"

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, terraform, amazon-dynamodb

I've defined the dynamodb table in terraform here:

```
name                   = "component_table"
  partition_key          = "name"
  partition_key_type     = "S"
  sort_key               = "version"
  billing_mode           = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
  environment            = "testing"
  aws_region             = "eu-west-1"
  restore_to_latest_time = true
  point_in_time_recovery = true
  extra_attributes = [
    {
      name = "version"
      type = "S"
    },
    {
      name = "team"
      type = "S"
    }
]
local_secondary_index = [
{
  name            = "TeamSecondaryIndex"
  projection_type = "ALL"
  range_key       = "team"
}
]
```

I've queried it with aws operator **GetItem**, I've defined name to be **abc** for testing purposes but can't seem to query a GetItem function as it says

```
The provided key element does not match the schema error
```

The function I ran is this:

```
func (m *Manager) ComponentGetByName(ctx context.Context, name string) (componentModel.Component, error) {

getItemInput := &awsDDB.GetItemInput{
            TableName: &m.cfg.tableName,
            Key: map[string]types.AttributeValue{
                "name": &types.AttributeValueMemberS{
                    Value: name,
                },
            },
        }
        getItemOutput, err := m.Client.GetItem(ctx, getItemInput)
return getItemOutput
}
```

I've left some details out such as converting getItemOutput into a component model for secrecy. I'm wondering why this happens and how can I resolve it? Open for a discussion. Thanks!

Comment: Your table definition doesn't seem to match the current specification for Terraform's [dynamodb_table](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/dynamodb_table), specifically in how pk/sk are indicated.

Comment: @jarmod I've just renamed them to specify that it is a pk/sk in terraform. It's neater that way imo, but it still is the pk/sk definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to do a GetItem using only the partition key value. To do a GetItem you must provide the full primary key which is Partition and sort key values. In your case `name` and `version` are required.

If you only know the Partition key, they you must perform [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) operation.

You must provide the name of the partition key attribute and a single value for that attribute. Query returns all items with that partition key value

Comment: That's why. Error logs from AWS can't really specify it so the confusion turns into panic. Cheers mate, I've scraped the sort key and have gone with GSI instead.